# Find a projective change of coordinates that maps the (projective) line L to the (projective) line G

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

> Let $L$, $G \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be lines. Show that there exists a projective change of coordinates $T$, such that $T(L)=G$.

This is how we defined a projective change of coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^2$:

> If $S$: $\mathbb{A}^3 \to\mathbb{A}^3$ is a linear affine change of coordiantes, then $S$ maps lines through the origin to lines through the origin again. So $S$ induces a map $S'$: $\mathbb{P}^2 \to\mathbb{P}^2$ which is called a projective change of coordinates.

I am not sure how to tackle this problem since I haven't got much more than the definition. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: If points in $\Bbb P^2$ correspond to lines through the origin in $\Bbb A^3$, what do lines in $\Bbb P^2$ correspond to? Can you figure out a way to map one of these objects on to another one of these objects?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then the lines of $\mathbb{P}^2$ are the planes of $\mathbb{A}^3$ that contain the $0$ (which are the $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{A}^3$ )

Comment: @KReiser Is there an easy argument why I can map (with an afiine change of coordinates) any plane in $\mathbb{A}^3$ going through $0$, to any other such plane?

Comment: Yes, you're correct that they're the planes. You ought to be able to do it with a linear map, right?

Comment: @KReiser well, it seems at least intuitive that I can do it with a linear map, since all I would need to do is rotate the plane. Not sure if thats an argument for it being linear. Also: would a linear map be enough? after all I need a linear change of coordinates (is that the same in that case)?

Comment: You should have enough tools from a linear algebra course you took at some point to prove that the invertible linear transformations act transitively on all linear subspaces of the same dimension. And yes, linear automorphisms are linear changes of coordinates.

Comment: @KReiser You are right, it is easy to show that this group action is transitive. Now I am just missing a proof for why linear automorphisms are change of coordinates, We defined a change of coordinates to be a polynomial map, so that every of the mapping polynomial has degree 1. I don't see why every automorphism should have this form.

Comment: This should be clear if you can write down what the map is. Do some examples and you should see it.

Comment: @KReiser I get it now! It's actually really simple because if I interpret the linear mapping as the multiplication of a matrix it is exactly the definition of the coordinate change. Thank you for your patience and the tips!